# What are the odds for a Pokemon being shiny in Pokemon Scarlet Violet?

Tags: pokemon-ninth-generation, pokemon-scarlet-violet

New Pokemon generations usually change something regarding shiny Pokemon, or they bring new mechanics to boost shiny Pokemon spawn.

Given that the brand new Generation 9 has just began, how do shiny Pokemon work now? Which are the odds for a wild Pokemon being shiny?

Comment: LOL what's the downvote for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like with most of the modern games, *Scarlet and Violet* share base Shiny odds of **1 in 4096**, [which the game itself kinda confirms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0BM0.jpg).

Using certain Sandwich recipes, players can activate something called **Sparkling Power**, a boost that will passively increase Shiny odds, with the maximum reached at level 3.

The **Shiny Charm** makes a return in *Scarlet and Violet*.

The final method for encountering wild Shinies with individually boosted odds is **Mass Outbreaks**, which work similarly to how they did in *Legends: Arceus*. Clearing Pokémon during a Mass Outbreak is how you increase Shiny odds, with modifiers kicking in after you clear 30 Pokémon and 60 Pokémon.

These are the combined odds:

| Bonus | Standard rate | Mass Outbreak rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Base | 1 in 4096 | 1 in 2048 (30 pkmn) 1 in 1365.67 (60 pkmn) |
| Shiny Charm | 1 in 1365.67 | 1 in 1024 (30 pkmn) 1 in 819 (60 pkmn) |
| Sparkling Power lv. 3 | 1 in 1024 | 1 in 819 (30 pkmn) 1 in 683 (60 pkms) |
| Sparkling Power lv. 3 & Shiny Charm | 1 in 683 | 1 in 585 (30 pkmn) 1 in 512 (60 pkmn) |

Source [here](https://dotesports.com/pokemon/news/what-are-the-shiny-odds-in-pokemon-scarlet-and-violet), pretty much confirmed by [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/scarletviolet/shinypokemon.shtml).

Comment: to be fair, the game even [explicitly mentions the 1 in 4000 rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0BM0.jpg) this time...

Comment: @Ꮢedacted weird, maybe it's just to give a rounded value. [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/scarletviolet/shinypokemon.shtml) states the usual 4096.

Comment: Yep, it is probably rounded, sorry if I was unclear - didn't mean you were wrong. I just wanted to point out that it has to be still the same 1 in 4096 since the game even references the value this time, you can safely add that to the answer if you wish

Comment: @Ꮢedacted oh, my bad, I'm used to that :) added your link as reference.